# Consolidating duplicate array items

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes...

```
array = [
{
    'keyword' => 'A',
    'total_value' => 50
},
{
    'keyword' => 'B',
    'total_value' => 25
},
{
    'keyword' => 'C',
    'total_value' => 40
},
{
    'keyword' => 'A',
    'total_value' => 10
},
{
    'keyword' => 'C',
    'total_value' => 15
}]
```

I need to consolidate the hashes with an identical `keyword` value. By consolidate, I mean combine `total_values`. For example, after consolidation of the above array, there should only be one hash with `'keyword' => 'A'` with a `'total_value => 60`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array =  [
{
    'keyword' => 'A',
    'total_value' => 50
},
{
    'keyword' => 'B',
    'total_value' => 25
},
{
    'keyword' => 'C',
    'total_value' => 40
},
{
    'keyword' => 'A',
    'total_value' => 10
},
{
    'keyword' => 'C',
    'total_value' => 15
}]

m = array.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |hs,i| 
    hs[i['keyword']] += i['total_value'] 
    hs 
end
p m
```

***Output:***

```
{"A"=>60, "B"=>25, "C"=>55}
```

> By consolidate, I mean combine total_values. For example, after consolidation of the above array, there should only be one hash with 'keyword' => 'A' with a 'total_value => 60

Here is how it can be done:

```
m = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |h,ob| 
     if h['keyword'] == 'A'
        h['total_value'] += ob['total_value']
        ob.update(h)
     end
end
p m
#=> {"keyword"=>"A", "total_value"=>60}
```

Comment: I just realized in my array, `keyword` and `total_value` are not in quotes. Will this solution still work?

Comment: I get this error `undefined method [] for #<OpenStruct keyword="A_KEYWORD", total_value="4369.75">`

Comment: The keys `keyword` and `total_value` in the array do not have quotes around them. Will that affect your solution?

Comment: Are you using `openstruct`?

Comment: It's a response from the google analytics core reporting API, so I guess it uses `openstruct`. I thought it was hashes because I could access the values using `hash.keyword`

Comment: @mnort9 Yes, that's is `openstruct` also behaves like hash. But with you example given is also looks good. Now the final output from the code of mine can be useful. You can us it as per your need.

Comment: I tried changing `Hash.new` to `OpenStruct.new`, but it produces the error: `undefined method each' for 0:Fixnum`. Will `inject` not work in a `OpenStruct`?

Comment: Yes... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16157699/consolidating-duplicate-openstruct-values-in-array

Comment: `hs[i['keyword']] = i['total_value'] + hs[i['keyword']]` could be clearer: `hs[i['keyword']] += i['total_value']`

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is doing this as you add items to a collection. Start to add an item, check if keyword is there. if (a) it's there, then just add new item's total_value to its. else (b) add new item to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.group_by{|h| h["keyword"]}
.map{|k, v| {
  "keyword" => k,
  "total_value" => v.map{|h| h["total_value"]}.inject(:+)
}}
```