# Combine hashes with identical symbol values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

```
array =
[ {
        :keyword => "A", 
        :total_value => "10"
    },
    {
        :keyword => "B", 
        :total_value => "5"
    },
    {
        :keyword => "C", 
        :total_value => "15"
    },
    {
        :keyword => "B", 
        :total_value => "6"
    },
    {
        :keyword => "A", 
        :total_value => "50"
    },
    {
        :keyword => "D", 
        :total_value => "40"
    },
    {
        :keyword => "A", 
        :total_value => "30"
    }]
```

I'm trying to consolidate the hashes with an identical `:keyword` value. By consolidate, I mean combine `:total_value`. For example, after consolidation...

```
new_array =
[ {
        :keyword => "A", 
        :total_value => "90"
    },
    {
        :keyword => "B", 
        :total_value => "11"
    },
    {
        :keyword => "C", 
        :total_value => "15"
    },
    {
        :keyword => "D", 
        :total_value => "40"
    }]
```

Comment: You keep asking the [same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16157699/479863) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16156691/479863) over and over again in slightly different forms. Why don't the answers to the other variations work here?

Comment: The original answer was correct for the data I supplied. However, I worded the question incorrectly and the solutions did not fix the issue for my actual data. I'm new to ruby, so I don't quite understand how to customize their solutions for my data.

Comment: To avoid confusion, it might be worthwhile to mention your previous question and explain how this one is different. This may not be obvious at first glance. An easy way to do this would be to put the desired output first, and give the input data second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is your friend:

```
combined_keywords = array.inject(Hash.new(0)){|acc, oh| acc[oh[:keyword]] += oh[:total_value].to_i ; acc }
```

Alternatively, the `each_with_object` method may be more readable in this case:

```
combined_keywords = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|oh, newh| newh[oh[:keyword]] += oh[:total_value].to_i }
```

The two methods above are functionally equivalent.

Last, if you really want this to be in the array-of-hashes style, this will get you there:

```
combined_keywords.collect{|(k,v)| {:keyword => k,  :total_value => v}}
```

Comment: `each_with_object` is sometimes less messy than an `inject` chain, but is nearly the same structurally.

Comment: Thanks, I always forget about each_with_object.  I've expanded the answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: The `inject` and `each_with_object` solutions should return a single hash with combined keywords as keys? For me, it's outputting a empty hash.

Comment: Yes, combined_keywords contains: `{"A"=>90, "B"=>11, "C"=>15, "D"=>40}`.  I'm on 1.9.3 here (it should work in 2.0 as well).  I copied/pasted your first block into irb, and this solution works against that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be something like this

```
new_array = {}
array.each do |hsh|
  new_array[hsh[:keyword]] ||= 0
  new_array[hsh[:keyword]] += hsh[:total_value].to_i
end
```

Comment: The output from that is going to look more like `{ "A" => 90, "B" => 11, "C" => 15, "D" => 40 }`, isn't it? Maybe you'd need another line on the end to iterate over keys and values in `new_array` to generate the desired array of hashes.